# How to Delete the previous image from the folder when updated by new image in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**I want to delete the previous image saved in folder and update new image in laravel  What is mistake in this code it doesnt work?**xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

code that stores data and image

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            $filename  = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->image->move(public_path('/uploads/image'), $fileNameToStore);
        }
        else
        {
            $fileNameToStore = 'No Img Found!';
        }
        $covidrecord = new Covidrecord();
        $covidrecord->fullname = $request->fullame;
        $covidrecord->image = $fileNameToStore;
        $covidrecord->save();
        if( $covidrecord->save())

        {
            return redirect()->route('store')->with(['msg'=>"User create successfully"]);
            return redirect()->route('store')->withError(['msg'=>"User cannot be registerd at the moment"]);

        }
    }
```

code to update data and image

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $covidrecord = Covidrecord::find($id);
    #Check if uploaded file already exist in Folder
    if($request->hasFile('product_image'))
    {
        #Get Image Path from Folder
        $path = 'uploads/image/'.$covidrecord->image;
        if(File::exists($path))
        {
            File::destroy($path);
        }

        #If File is new and not Exist in Folder
        $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename  = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
        $request->product_image->move(public_path('/uploads/image'), $fileNameToStore);

        $covidrecord->product_image = $fileNameToStore;
       if($covidrecord->save())
       {
        dd('Product updated Successfully');

       }
       else{
        dd('Product update Failed');

       }
     }
}
```

There is red line in File

Answer (score 0):

The public path method is missing while you are generating a path to check file existence in the update method

```
$path = public_path().'/uploads/image/'.$covidrecord->image;
    if(File::exists($path))
    {
        File::destroy($path);
    }
```